# Consistency order of composition method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

> Let $\Psi^h$ be the evolution operator of a single step method of consistency order $p$, where $p$ is even. Let $\gamma_1,\gamma_2,\gamma_3$ be real numbers such that $\gamma_1+\gamma_2+\gamma_3=1$ and $\gamma_1^{p+1}+\gamma_2^{p+1}+\gamma_3^{p+1}=0$. Define $\tilde \Psi^h=\Psi^{\gamma_3 h}\circ \Psi^{\gamma_2 h}\circ \Psi^{\gamma_1 h}$. Show that $\tilde \Psi^h$ has consistency order $p+1$.

So I need to show $\Vert \Phi^h y - \tilde \Psi^h y\Vert \leq C h^{p+2}$ (where $\Phi^h$ is the flow of the ODE) locally uniformly. By consistency of $\Psi^h$ we have $\Psi^{\gamma_1 h}y=\Phi^{\gamma_1 h}+C (\gamma_1 h)^{p+1}+O(h^{p+2})$. Now if I apply the second step, how do I handle this term? Does this approach even work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, note that

\begin{align}
\Phi^h y -  \tilde{\Psi}^hy =& 
\,\Phi^{\gamma_3h}\circ\Phi^{\gamma_2h}\circ\Phi^{\gamma_1h}y 
- \Psi^{\gamma_3h}\circ\Psi^{\gamma_2h}\circ\Psi^{\gamma_1h}y\\
=&\, \Phi^{\gamma_3h}\circ\Phi^{\gamma_2h}\circ\Phi^{\gamma_1h}y 
- \Psi^{\gamma_3h}\circ\Psi^{\gamma_2h}\circ\Phi^{\gamma_1h}y\\
&+\Psi^{\gamma_3h}\circ\Psi^{\gamma_2h}\circ\Phi^{\gamma_1h}y 
- \Psi^{\gamma_3h}\circ\Psi^{\gamma_2h}\circ\Psi^{\gamma_1h}y\,.
\end{align}
As you said,
$$\Vert \Phi^{\gamma_1h}y - \Psi^{\gamma_1h}y\Vert \leq C_1(\gamma_1h)^{p+1}
+\mathcal{O}(h^{p+2})\,,$$
for a constant $C_1$ that depends on $y$.
By consistency of $\Psi$, it follows
$$\Vert\Psi^{\gamma_3h}\circ\Psi^{\gamma_2h}\circ\Phi^{\gamma_1h}y 
- \Psi^{\gamma_3h}\circ\Psi^{\gamma_2h}\circ\Psi^{\gamma_1h}y \Vert
\leq C_1(\gamma_1h)^{p+1}+\mathcal{O}(h^{p+2})\,.$$
Next, you take care of the $\gamma_2$-term.  Similarly to what we did above,
\begin{align}
\Phi^{\gamma_3h}\circ\Phi^{\gamma_2h}\circ\Phi^{\gamma_1h}y 
- \Psi^{\gamma_3h}\circ\Psi^{\gamma_2h}\circ\Phi^{\gamma_1h}y =&
\Phi^{\gamma_3h}\circ\Phi^{\gamma_2h}\circ\Phi^{\gamma_1h}y 
- \Psi^{\gamma_3h}\circ\Phi^{\gamma_2h}\circ\Phi^{\gamma_1h}y \\
&+\Psi^{\gamma_3h}\circ\Phi^{\gamma_2h}\circ\Phi^{\gamma_1h}y 
- \Psi^{\gamma_3h}\circ\Psi^{\gamma_2h}\circ\Phi^{\gamma_1h}y
\end{align}
And again,
$$\Vert\Psi^{\gamma_3h}\circ\Phi^{\gamma_2h}\circ\Phi^{\gamma_1h}y 
- \Psi^{\gamma_3h}\circ\Psi^{\gamma_2h}\circ\Phi^{\gamma_1h}y\Vert
\leq C_2(\gamma_2h)^{p+1}
+\mathcal{O}(h^{p+2})\,,$$
for a constant $C_2$ that depends on $\Phi^{\gamma_1h}y$.

Finally,
$$\Vert\Phi^{\gamma_3h}\circ\Phi^{\gamma_2h}\circ\Phi^{\gamma_1h}y 
- \Psi^{\gamma_3h}\circ\Phi^{\gamma_2h}\circ\Phi^{\gamma_1h}y \Vert
\leq C_3(\gamma_3h)^{p+1}+\mathcal{O}(h^{p+2})\,,$$
for a constant $C_3$ that depends on $\Phi^{\gamma_2h}\circ\Phi^{\gamma_1h}y$.

Assuming that the right-hand side of your ODE is Lipschitz in $y$,
we can bound $C_1$, $C_2$ and $C_3$ by a bigger constant $C_4$ that depends
on $y$ only.

Thus, splitting $\Vert \Phi^h y -  \tilde{\Psi}^hy  \Vert$ with the triangle inequality and assuming $\gamma_1^{p+1}+\gamma_2^{p+1}+\gamma_3^{p+1}=0$,
you can conclude that the new method $\tilde{\Psi}$ has consistency order $p+1$.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I'm not sure how to justify the step after "By consistency of $\Psi$ [...]", does it follow from the characterization of consistency via the increment function, i.e. $\Psi^h y=y+h \psi(y,h)$?

Comment: @ManfredHohler, exactly. Do you see why?

Comment: Do I just use this twice to get $\Psi^{\gamma_3h}\circ\Psi^{\gamma_2h}\circ\Phi^{\gamma_1h}y 
- \Psi^{\gamma_3h}\circ\Psi^{\gamma_2h}\circ\Psi^{\gamma_1h}y 
= C_1(\gamma_1h)^{p+1}+\mathcal{O}(h^{p+2})$? (Since $\Psi^hy=y+\mathcal{O}(h)$).

Comment: @ManfreHohler, yes you do ^_^